# add multi chart with multi axes label using chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart, linechart

```js
    function createDiagonalPattern(color = 'black') {
      let shape = document.createElement('canvas')
      shape.width = 10
      shape.height = 10
      let c = shape.getContext('2d')
      c.strokeStyle = color
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(2, 0)
      c.lineTo(10, 8)
      c.stroke()
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(0, 8)
      c.lineTo(2, 10)
      c.stroke()
      return c.createPattern(shape, 'repeat')
    }
      var barChartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                type: 'bar',
                  label: "Visitor",
                    data: [200, 185, 590, 621, 250, 400, 95],
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: createDiagonalPattern('grey'),
                    borderColor: 'grey',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
                    yAxisID: 'y1'
            }, {
                label: "Sales",
                    type:'line',
                    data: [51, 65, 40, 49, 60, 37, 40],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    backgroundColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointBorderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    pointRadius: 10,
                    pointHoverRadius: 15,
                    pointBorderWidth:3,
                    yAxisID: 'y'
            } ]
        };

                window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                responsive: true,
                tooltips: {
                  mode: 'label'
              },
              elements: {
                line: {
                    fill: false
                }
            },
              scales: {
                  y: {
                      type: "linear",
                      display: false,
                      position: "left",
                      gridLines:{
                          display: false
                      },
                      labels: {
                          show:true,
                      }
                  },
                  y1: {
                      type: "linear",
                      display: false,
                      position: "right",
                      gridLines:{
                          display: false
                      },
                      labels: {
                          show:true,

                      }
                  } }
            }
            });
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to make bar and line chart together but while handling the axes label is not working properly

I am using chart js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>

    function createDiagonalPattern(color = 'black') {
      let shape = document.createElement('canvas')
      shape.width = 10
      shape.height = 10
      let c = shape.getContext('2d')
      c.strokeStyle = color
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(2, 0)
      c.lineTo(10, 8)
      c.stroke()
      c.beginPath()
      c.moveTo(0, 8)
      c.lineTo(2, 10)
      c.stroke()
      return c.createPattern(shape, 'repeat')
    }
      var barChartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                type: 'bar',
                  label: "Visitor",
                    data: [200, 185, 590, 621, 250, 400, 95],
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: createDiagonalPattern('grey'),
                    borderColor: 'grey',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
                    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
            }, {
                label: "Sales",
                    type:'line',
                    data: [51, 65, 40, 49, 60, 37, 40],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    backgroundColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointBorderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: '#2E41CF',
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    pointRadius: 10,
                    pointHoverRadius: 15,
                    pointBorderWidth:3,
                    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
            } ]
        };

                window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                responsive: true,
                tooltips: {
                  mode: 'label'
              },
              elements: {
                line: {
                    fill: false
                }
            },
              scales: {
                x: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: true
                    },
                    position: 'top',
                    labels: {
                        show: false,
                    }
                }],
                y: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    display: false,
                    position: "left",
                    id: "y-axis-1",
                    gridLines:{
                        display: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        show:true,

                    }
                }, {
                    type: "linear",
                    display: false,
                    position: "right",
                    id: "y-axis-2",
                    gridLines:{
                        display: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        show:true,

                    }
                }]
            }
            }
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I  have tried the code which i have already mentioned above

and got this result
[my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxwIU.png)

but
my expected result should be I could not able to shift my sales to right axes label

[expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7c4e.png)

Comment: @Balkishan Dhaker's answer is correct, your scales were set wrong. But you changed your question to incorporate his answer so now nobody understands what the problem was. Please revert to the original form of the code (only) so it becomes useful for other users that set the axes the wrong way as you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the scale wrong maybe this can help

```
scales: {
         "y-axis-2":
            {
                type: "linear",
                display: true,
                position: "left",
                gridLines:{
                    display: false
                },
                labels: {
                    show:true,

                }
            },  "y-axis-1": {
                type: "linear",
                display: true,
                position: "right",
                gridLines:{
                    display: false
                },
                labels: {
                    show:true,

                }
            }
        }
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html

Comment: Or you can use existing ids also in string in above example you can use "y-axis-1", "y-axis-2"

Comment: I did, not working even after the implementation the existing axis are also not visible

Comment: I have added the code in snippet kindly check

Comment: Updated the correct scales config, check now. its working as needed. display is set to false in your config. that's why it was not visible in.

Comment: I have updated the answer have you checked that?